# How Would I Begin This Proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $T: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear transformation such that there is no nonzero ${\bf x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $T({\bf x}) = {\bf 0}$. Let $S$ be a linearly independet subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $T(S):=\{T({\bf x}): {\bf x} \in S\}$ is linearly independent

So, here's what I understand. $T$ is a linear transformation such that only $0$ can make the statement $T(x)=0$ true. And then, there is a linearly independent subset $S$. We must then prove there is an $x$ in $S$ such that the linear transformation $T(x)$ is linearly independent. Now, I am not very sure where to start this proof. Can someone possibly guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be a linear independent set. Because it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, it can contain of at most $n$ vectors. Suppose it contains $k < n$ vectors and write $S = \{v_1,\dots, v_k\}$

Then, we have to prove that $T(S) = \{T(v_1), \dots, T(v_k)\}$ is linearly independent.

To do this, let us consider the following linear combination that is equal to $0$:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^k a_iT(v_i) = 0$$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for $i = 1,2 , \dots,k$

By definition, we have to prove that $a_i = 0$ for $i = 1,2,3, \dots, k$ is the only possibility for this linear combination to be equal to $0$

By linearity of $T$, we have:

$$0 = \sum_{i = 1}^k a_iT(v_i) = T\left(\sum_{i = 1}^k a_iv_i\right)$$

Because $T(x) = 0 \iff x = 0$, it must follow that $$\sum_{i = 1}^k a_iv_i = 0$$

and hence, because $\{v_1,\dots, v_k\}$ is linearly independent, it follows that $a_i = 0$ for $i = 1,2, \dots, k$, such that $T(S)$ is linear independent, as desired.

Comment: This was really well put. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm curious though, what should my thought process be when attempting to prove a certain statement? I feel like I never really know how to properly begin proving a certain algebraic statement.

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can accept it :)

Comment: Well, you have the definition to begin with: you must prove that $T(S)$ is linear independent, so use the definition: take a linear combination of such elements, and show that all the coefficients must be $0$. While proving this, you will need to use the assumptions: $S$ is linear dependent, and $T(x) = 0 \iff x = 0$

Comment: As an exercise, you can prove that $T(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0$ is equivalent with $T$ being injective, which is equivalent with the statement you have to prove.

Comment: According to the question, $m \geq n$. One more thing, you can consider that there are $k (\leq n)$ independent vectors in $S$.

Comment: Ah I didn't see the codomain was $R^m$, so the usage of $m$ in my proof was unfortunate. Editing right now.

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice. Since you have to prove that $T(S)$ is linearly independent, your proof must start with a linear combination of elements of $T(S)$ which gives the zero vector.

Then, try to use the properties of $T$ (linearity+...)